# Setting user-agent for headers swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to set custom header in my request, which works but for an issue.

I have my key as `user-agent` but when I print my headers, it shows as `User-Agent`.

```
urlRequest.setValue(Bundle.main.buildNumber, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-build-cc")
urlRequest.setValue("Custom send", forHTTPHeaderField: "user-agent")
```

while `x-build-cc` comes up as expected, `user-agent` becomes capitalized.

Comment: Is that a problem? Does anything fail when it reads the differently capitalised `User-Agent`?

Comment: The header is being targeted from the backend and need it to be lowercase.

Comment: If you can, you should update the backend in question. As defined in RFC-2616 (http protocol) header fields are case insensitive